# The digits are blinking on 7 seg display with 8051 microcontroller

Tags: c, interrupt, interrupt-handling, 8051, nxp-microcontroller

I wrote program in C for microcontroller 8051 architecture who receive data from serial port and show on 7seg display, but digits are blinking. Can you help me to solve this problem. The Processor is 80C32. 4051 Multiplexer is connected with microcontroller and selects displays. There are 5 7seg display, who are through ULN2803 connected with microcontroller.Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
enter code here

#include <reg51.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayDigit(unsigned char cifra);
void delayTimer();
void showNumber(); //receive data from serial port and store data in buffer buff
void initSerial(); // serial port initialization
char receiveData();
void delay(unsigned int msdelay);
char buff[20]; // store data from serial port
unsigned int tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5;
int tail=0; // index of element in buffer buff
sbit A=P3^4;   // A is pin on 4051 Multiplexer
sbit BB=P3^5;  // BB is pin on 4051 Multiplexer
sbit C=P3^6;  // C is pin on 4051 Multiplexer
sbit INH=P3^7; // INH pin on 4051 Multiplexer

void main(void)
{
   P1=0x00;
   P3=0x03;
   PT0=1;
   while(1)
   {
     initSerial();
     showNumber();
     delayTimer(); 
   }
}

// mask
void displayDigit(unsigned char cifra)
{
   switch(cifra)
   {
     case 0: P1=0x3F; break;
     case 1: P1=0x06; break;
     case 2: P1=0x5B; break;
     case 3: P1=0x4F; break;
     case 4: P1=0x66; break;
     case 5: P1=0x6D; break;
     case 6: P1=0x7D; break;
     case 7: P1=0x07; break;
     case 8: P1=0x7F; break;
     case 9: P1=0x6F; break;
  }
}

// refresh display - a 
void delayTimer()
{
  TMOD&=0xF0;
  TMOD|=0x01;
  TH0=0xFF;
  TL0=0xFF;
  ET0=1;
  EA=1;
  TR0=1;
  while(TF0==0);
  TF0=0;
  TR0=0;
}

// serial port initialization
void initSerial()
{
  SCON=0xD0;
  TMOD&=0x0F;
  TMOD|=0x20;
  TH1=0xFD;
  TR1=1;
}

// receive data
char receiveData()
{
  char el;
  while(RI==0);
  el=SBUF;
  RI=0;
  return el;
}

// receive data from serial port and store data in buffer
void showNumber()
{ 
  int tail=0; 
  char el;
  el=receiveData();
  if(el==0x02) // start of communication
  {
    buff[tail]=el;
    tail++;
    while(el!=0x03)
    {
      el=receiveData();
      if(el!=0x03)
      {
        buff[tail]=el;
        tail++;
      }
      else
      {
        buff[tail]=el;
        tail++;
        buff[tail]='\0';
      }
      if(tail==20)
        tail=0;
    } 
  }
  else if(el==0x03) // end of communication
  {
    buff[tail]=el;
    tail++;
    buff[tail]='\0'; 
  } 
} 
// show on display
void timer0(void) interrupt 1
{
  int i;
  tmp5=buff[3]-'0';
  tmp4=buff[4]-'0'; 
  tmp3=buff[5]-'0';
  tmp2=buff[6]-'0';
  tmp1=buff[7]-'0'; 
  if(tmp5==0 && tmp4==0 && tmp3==0 && tmp2==0) // 1 digit on display
  {
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp1);
      delay(8);
    }
  }
  else if(tmp5==0 && tmp4==0 && tmp3==0) // 2 digits on display
  {
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp1);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp2);
      delay(8);
    }
  }
  else if(tmp5==0 && tmp4==0) // 3 digits on display
  {
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp1);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp2);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp3);
      delay(8);
    }
  }
  else if(tmp5==0) // 4 digits on display
  {
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp1);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp2);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp3);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=1;
      BB=0;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp4);
      delay(8);
    }
  }
  else  // 5 digits on display
  {
    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp1);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp2);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=0;
      BB=1;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp3);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=1;
      BB=0;
      A=0;
      displayDigit(tmp4);
      delay(8);
      INH=0;
      C=1;
      BB=0;
      A=1;
      displayDigit(tmp5);
      delay(8);
    }
  }
}

void delay(unsigned int msdelay)
{
  unsigned int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<msdelay;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<100;j++);
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh? 8 milliseconds delay between digits is *way* too much for multiplexing, with 5 digits that makes for max 1/(5*40e-3) =~ 5 fps, so of course that will be flickery.

Comment: Why do you re-initialize the serial port over and over? Never use `char` for storing raw data. Keep interrupts short - you should just set a flag there then do the actual work in main. And so on. Once you got this working, I would recommend going through https://codereview.stackexchange.com, because there's way too many problems here. Tag it [tag:embedded].

Comment: How short should I keep interrupts? Should I set flag in interrupt function? Instead of char, what should I use for storing raw data?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to help you:

1. enable the UART RX interrupt.  Have that interrupt handler do
   == disable interrupts
   == if received byte is 0x02 then:
   ==== set buffIndex to 0 
   ==== set global flag indicating receiving next message
   == else if received byte is 0x03 set flag indicting full message available
   == else save char at next position in buff[] and increment buffIndex
   == clear the UART RX interrupt pending flag
   == exit
2. the code should be implementing a 'double buffer' so the background processing 'main' has time to process the new message.
3. which ever buffer is receiving byte should be considered the 'active' buffer
   which ever buffer is displaying the message should be considered the 'inactive' buffer
4. The `main` sits on a spin-loop waiting for a message to be available.
   main will then immediately reset the 'message available' flag
5. For maximum robustness, the displaying of the message should be completed in less than 1 millisecond so the displaying of the characters must have delays that are only long enough for the mux to settle.
   such mux settling time should be in the microseconds, not milliseconds
   The displaying of the message is 'serial' and has no timing (other than waiting for the mux to settle) so suggest not placing that on an interrupt.
6. Does your hardware have a data latch for each digit?  If so, then there is no need to write a digit more than once so can eliminate those loops that write the same data over and over.

Comment: I did it, but digits are still blinking. I don't have a data latch for each digit, so I use for loops. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Of course the digits will blink.  The digit 'disappears' when the digit is not being selected.  I.E. your hardware really needs a data latch for each digit, so the code can set the digit and go on to other activities.  With a data latch, the digit will stay the same until the code comes around to change the value in the data latch